# Why Euro Truck Simulator 2 not using my laptop's GPU?

Tags: graphics-card, euro-truck-simulator-2

Please see this screenshot of task manager (Windows 10):
[image]

As you can see, for any other game (like Counter Strike, Half Life), software like Adobe Photoshop, the GPU engine is shown **GPU 1** (that is my NVIDIA 940MX graphics card).

But the cell under GPU engine is empty for Euro Truck Simulator game. It should either be GPU 0 (Intel HD) or GPU 1. But it's empty.

I noticed it suddenly today, when I realized my game is not that smooth even when I have a good laptop. I had a cheap laptop and had similar performance for the same game.

I also checked NVIDIA settings, where GPU is enabled for this game. See this also:

[image]

So what is the issue? Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! Actually it was using NVIDIA graphics card (GPU 1). The reason it was not shown in task manager was because the game was minimized at that time. I minimized the game to check performance in task manager, hence it was not shown at that time.

**How did I know it using GPU 1 when game is not minimized? :**

I pressed Shift Key 5 times accidently, and it minimized game as Sticky Keys notification appeared. While this my task manager was already open and for **1-2** seconds I observed **GPU 1 - 3D** written against Euro Truck game! It was just *vanishing*!

Comment: In future to troubleshoot, you can also look in Performance tab -> GPU under Task Manager.